# nginx subdomain servers default page

Tags: nginx

I'm new to nginx and trying to use a subdomain on the server. The main domain is pointed at another server. I setup `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_app` like so, but am still getting the default nginx page instead of my app.

The app displays correctly when I go to the server IP directly. From my searches, usually the default nginx page is served when the `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` is still present, but I've removed it.

I restarted nginx a few times with `service nginx restart`, but am lost at what else I should look at.

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.doindie_production.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  root /home/deploy/apps/app_name/current/public;
  server_name sub.mydomain.com www.sub.mydomain.com;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I do have a few errors like this in my `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, but if I try to visit the subdomain, it doesn't not create a new error with the current timestamp, so I don't know how relevent this is:

```
2014/05/12 18:10:20 [error] 1180#0: *16932 open() "/home/deploy/apps/my app/current/public/assets/social-icons.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), 
client: IP, server: sub.mydomain.com, request: "GET /assets/social-icons.png HTTP/1.1", 
host: "myserver", referrer: "myserver/assets/application-c57f876dbf7635dc786f21256ae0476f.css"
```

Comment: are you getting some error in the error logs or anything like that?

Comment: added one, but not sure if it's relevant. Where should I be looking for logs? Just ```var/log/nginx```? cheers

Comment: The first line say's that it did not found the path to the image file specified. I don't know if you've modified the path or not, but you have it set wrong in the config obviously.

Comment: So the obvious question: are you visiting your server? If you request it by subdomain, do you get an entry in the access log? If not, check your DNS.